# get sum each month

Tags: sql, aggregate

I have SQL like this:

```
SELECT (to_char(date_buy, 'mm')||'/'||to_char(date_buy, 'yyyy')||': '||SUM(quantity)) month
FROM production_hist
WHERE date_buy > SYSDATE-365
AND product_no ='714'
GROUP BY to_char(date_buy, 'mm')||'/'||to_char(date_buy, 'yyyy')
```

I got the result like this

```
month
07/2019: 200
08/2019: 100
09/2019: 250
```

I want to have a result like this:

```
Month
01/2019-02/2019-03/2019-04/2019-05/2019-06/2019-07/2019-08/2019-09/2019-10/2019-11/2019-12/2019
   0      0       0        0       0       0       200     100      250    0       0      0
```

Anyone can help with this?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN date_buy >= date '2019-01-01' and date_buy < date '2019-02-01'
             THEN quantity ELSE 0
        END) as qty_201901,
       (CASE WHEN date_buy >= date '2019-02-01' and date_buy < date '2019-02-01'
             THEN quantity ELSE 0
        END) as qty_201902,
       . . .
FROM production_hist
WHERE date_buy > SYSDATE-365 AND
      product_no = 714     -- presumably a number so no quotes
```